# AWS Lambda Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I got a graphql server running in Lambda, and everything works fine and I want my endpoint to only be accessible by authenticated users, my authentication providers are cognito identity with cognito user pool and facebook. So how can I check if the user sending request is authenticated? I'm new to AWS so, my question might confusing for AWS experts, but the main issue I have is "how can I check if the request is from authenticated user"? should I use AWS_IAM as authorizer or should custom authorizer?

What I initially did was setup a custom authorizer that checks if the accessToken from congito is valid, but I think this is not the right way and this will only work for cognito but not for facebook users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to check anything... in API Gateway, select your lambda method, and in Method Request box, select "Auth: AWS_IAM" and then only logged in cognito users will be able to call your lambda method

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, greatly appreciated. But will it work for my federated identities? I mean for facebook users as well? and do I have to include any token to my request header?

Comment: yes, it will work with any cognito user type. check this repo: https://github.com/mhart/aws4 you need to sign each api call

Comment: thank you so much, for you response, I just need to figure our how can I integrate this with apolloClient.